# how do I send a text field input from the frontend to the backend

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I have made a website, it uses react as the frontend and Django as the backend. I am trying to get input from the frontend and send it to the backend, it doesn't seem to be working. the problem is that when I try to print it the text input sent from the front end is not being printed.
here's the code:

```
searchSong(e) {
    this.setState({
        search: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state.search)
}
```

this is what makes the text field input :

```
                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Song" variant="outlined" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.searchSong} />
                <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={this.addButtonPressed}>Search Song</Button>
```

these are the functions that send the text input from the frontend to the backend and the states :

```
addButtonPressed() {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      search: this.state.search,
    })
  };
  fetch("/spotify/search-song/", requestOptions)
}

searchSong(e) {
    this.setState({
        search: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state.search)
}
```

the state :

```
  this.state = {
      search: ""
  }
```

here's the function that I made which will test if I got the correct text field input :

```
def search_song(session_id, song_name):
    search_letters = "playlist/?type=" + song_name
    print(search_letters)
```

this is the view that uses the function :

```
class SearchSong(APIView):
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'search'
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not request.session.exists(request.session.session_key):
            request.session.create()
        room_code = self.request.session.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
        music = str(request.data.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg))
        room = Room.objects.filter(code=room_code)[0]
        search_song(room.host, music)
```

this is the endpoint being called by the frontend :

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('search-song', SearchSong.as_view())
]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem here, are you getting an error?

Comment: no, when I try to print it the text input sent from the front end is not being printed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**in your `urls.py`:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

    urlpatterns = [ ⬇⬇
    path('search-song/', SearchSong.as_view())

]
```

**SearchSong.js:**
Give full path with **'/'**

```
addButtonPressed() {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      search: this.state.search,
    })
  };    ⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇                                    ⬇⬇⬇
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/spotify/search-song/", requestOptions)
}
```